Linked Server not connecting to SQL Server 2022 database
I have a SQL Server 2019 Enterprise database in a data center far, far away. I have a SQL Server 2019 developer edition database on my local laptop (A), and it is a Linked Server on the far away database (B). The security is based on a local SQL login on the A database. Everything works fine. I do development work and test the B database where I create JOINs back to my A database.
My IT group just issued a new laptop to me. I installed SQL Server 2022 developer edition and now I have the database (C) configured just like the one on my old laptop A. However, I cannot create a Linked Server connection to the C database from the B database. I have confirmed about 49 times that the SQL login account is exactly the same for both A and C databases. I have deleted and re-created the Linked Server from B to A multiple times today, and it works fine. But when I try to create a Linked Server from B to C, I receive an error message that the connection failed.

I have noticed in SQL Config Mgr that there are no Client Protocols on the C database. Apparently this went away with SQL 2022. I don't think this is the issue; I have made sure the port numbers on C match what is on A, which is 1433. I have restarted the SQL Browser service on C multiple times but this did not help.
I have laptops A and C sitting side by side, and I cannot see any difference in the way the databases are configured. What am I missing?

Based on the error, I would make sure that:

Laptop C's database is listening on the same port as Laptop A's
Windows Firewall on laptop C is allowing traffic from Server B to laptop C

Good luck, hope you find the answer soon.

Ii really don't think that opening the port is a good idea, as it makes the computer vulnerable, establish an encrypted connection makes the system secure

I confirmed that databases on both A and C and configured with IPAll=1433. I then tried a telnet into laptop C with port 1433 and it did not connect, so I am looking for more  information on checking firewall settings in Windows 11 which is the OS for laptop C.
